# Spring JPA + Hibernate + Rest services + long time transactions

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I am using Spring JPA + Hibernate.
I have a master for creation data, which call many  REST services. They are located in one @ApiV1RestController, and their implementation is in one @Service.
At different steps, I need to add data, process it, and commit at the end.

Example:

REST 1:
/addItems
Adding item

```
Item item = new Item();
item.setDescr("test");
itemRepository.flush();
```

REST 2:
/addLocs
Adding locations

```
Loc loc = new Loc();
loc.setDescr("test");
locRepository.flush();
```

REST 3:
/checkItemLocs
Executing a stored procedure where i work with data from previous REST-s

Step n. Commit

How to make the rest work in one transaction. Now the commit is automatically performed at the end of each rest service

I tried to use flush and @transactional

Comment: REST means State-Transfer. You are misusing it like a RPC.